# Update запрос с конкатенацией строки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть обычный update-запрос

```
 $db_query = "update " . DB_PREF . "advert set key_words='" .$_POST['key_word'] . "' where id_advert=32";
 $q_ident = mysql_query($db_query, $dbcnx);
```

Как в колонку `key_words` записать это значение `POST`'а, но только, чтобы не перезаписывалось текущее значение, а просто к нем прибавлялось?

Обычно с числами делаю так  `set key_words= +` число,  а вот как со строками  не пойму.

Догадываюсь, что сначала надо делать выборку,а потом уже суммировать значение из выборки и `POST`'а.

Comment: У вас в `key_words` через запятую перечислены значения или пробел или как? как в итоге должно выглядеть?

Comment: это одно слово  или текст будет .. key_words - это произвольно так назвал

Answer (score 5):

Для обновления значений ничего выбирать не нужно. В MySQL для конкатенации строк есть специальная функция [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Update-запрос с ее использованием имеет вид:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET key_words = CONCAT(key_words, 'добавочный постфикс') WHERE id = 32;
```

**Замечание:**

В коде вы используете библиотеку `mysql`, которая уже давно помечена как устаревшая. Советую посмотреть на более современные библиотеки для взаимодействия с MySQL: [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) и [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).

Кроме того, вы используете конкатенацию строк для построения SQL. Это неверный подход, он создает огромный простор для выполнения [SQL-инъекций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Для устранения уязвимостей такого рода, все пользовательские данные, попадающие в запрос, должны эскейпироваться. Это может быть сделано как в ручную(`mysql(i)_real_escape_string`), так и автоматически с помощью плейсхолдеров и подготовленных выражений PDO.

Comment: спасибо ..Помогли

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian, если я полностью ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте ответ как "принятый" (галочка слева от вопроса).

Answer (score 2):

В этом запросе нет **ничего** обычного.

Это запрос, который обновляет кривую структуру БД и делает это небезопасным способом.

Ключевые слова должны храниться в **отдельной таблице**. И тогда не придется колупаться с обновлением строк.

А для вставки надо использовать **подготовленные выражения**, а не пихать данные в запрос напрямую.

Comment: Да, вы безусловно правы рассуждая о подготовленных выражениях и кривой структуре БД. Но ваш ответ не поможет ТС решить его проблему. Совсем. Отвечать рассуждениями вида "_нужно все переписать_" на вопрос о конкретной локализованной проблеме, как минимум, не конструктивно.